# Looping alert is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made onclick alert which is ok for just alert simple ,but I try to alert with loop ,it is only work for one times action to loop finished .In second click it's can't show alert box...!!!

```
 <ul>
    <li>Click one</li>
    <li>Click two</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var n = 1;
    var txt = "Now you can see me";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$(document).unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
        $(document).off('click').on('click', function() {
            for (n; n <= 10; n++) {
                alert(txt + " for " + n + " times"); //after finished loop can't show alert
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have tried using with unbind and off trigger()?Why doesn't work in second time click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize n to 1 before starting again.

```
   <script>
    var n = 1;
    var txt = "Now you can see me";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$(document).unbind('click').bind('click', function(){
        $(document).off('click').on('click', function() {
            for (n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
                alert(txt + " for " + n + " times"); //after finished loop can't show alert
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why was need to assign ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @DavidJawphan You could have assigned before the loop itself but assinging is necessary since once the loop is done the value of n will be 10 and will not be reset. Next time for loop will check its condition and won't go inside.

Comment: @DavidJawphan When you use an already initialized variable, use `for` loop like following : `var i = 0; for (; i < 9; i++) { console.log(i); }` (source : [Mozilla Developper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v3n00pxn/).